# Scheme programming, going through a list and making everything inside a list

Tags: list, recursion, recursion-schemes

homework question:

`(diginlist '(4 5 3 2 8))` is supposed to return `(4(5(3)2)8)`

```
(define(removelast L)
  (if(null?(cdr L)) '()
     (cons(car L) removelast(cdr L))))

(define(last L) (if(null?(cdr L)) (car L) (last(cdr L))))

(define(diginlist L)
  (cond((null? L) '())
       ((list?(car L)) ((diginlist(car L))
                           (list(diginlist(cdr L)))))
       (else(append(list(diginlist(cdr L)))))))

(diginlist '(4 5 3 2 8))
```

returns:

`(list (list (list (list (list '())))))`

I know I am supposed to incorporate removelast and last, but I am having trouble doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You must learn to think recursively. Given an instance of the problem P, the goal is to construct a smaller instance of the problem R such that the solution to R can be easily "augmented" to build a solution for P.

Once the problem is decomposed in this way, you can solve R with a recursive call to the same procedure meant to solve P.

In this case, P is to "listify" `(4 5 3 2 8)`.  Then what is R?  Well if we could listify `(5 3 2)` to obtain `(5 (3) 2)`, then we'd be in good shape. 
We'd only need to augment this solution by making it the second element in a 3 element list where the first element is 4 and the last is 8.

The base cases are when the input is empty or has exactly one element. In those cases, we want to return the input.

Putting this together as pseudocode:

```
 function listify (lst)
   if lst has 0 or 1 elements, return lst
   otherwise
     split lst into 3 parts:
       F = first element of lst
       M = a copy of lst except with first and last elements omitted
       L = last element of lst
     return a list of 3 elements: (F (listify M) L)
```

Now express this in Scheme. You have some of it done.